# Alert when reaching bottom of the page alerts when I am at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to call an alert when I get to the bottom of the page. But for some reason it calls the alert when I scroll to the top of the page. It works in IE but when I use the code in chrome or Mozilla it doesn't.

I also notice that if I zoom in on chrome or out it stops working at the top of the page too. I've searched for answers for this and have seen references to similar problems but as such haven't found an answer.

If anyone can shed any light on this I'd really appreciate it. Here is is the the JS code that I have been using.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var load = 0;
    var nbr = '1';
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        alert(nbr);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It's seems to work in Chrome.. http://jsbin.com/kehemej

Comment: Thank you. While it didn't answer my question it did point me toward a problem with other code I had. It's fixed now.

Comment: Don’t handle scroll events like this, it is incredibly bad for performance. http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: @Niall Please post your answer and accept it as soon as you can if you think it can help others too. If not, you should delete the question to help clean up the site. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give your document a document type for `$(window).height()` to work as you intend:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

By adding this you enforce strict mode as opposed to quirks mode.

jQuery does not support quirks mode as explained in the [jQuery 1.8.1 release notes](https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/):

> Don’t use [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)! jQuery has never supported Quirks mode and we do not perform any testing in Quirks. This can affect values like `$("window").height()`

Comment: Nice! I never would have guessed. How do you figure that?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel="relativeanchor"]').click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
      }, 500);
      return false;
    });
  });
  </script>
  <style media="screen">
  body { background-color: #000; color: #fff; }
  a { color: aqua; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <body>
    <h1 id="top">How to make smooth scrolling.</h1>
    <a href="#mysection1" rel="relativeanchor">Section 1</a>
    <a href="#mysection2" rel="relativeanchor">Section 2</a>
    <div style="height: 1500px;">This requires jQuery. <a href="#top" rel="relativeanchor">Go Back to Top</a></div>
    <div id="mysection1">Section 1</div>
    <div style="height: 1500px;">This requires jQuery. <a href="#top" rel="relativeanchor">Go Back to Top</a></div>
    <div id="mysection2">Section 2</div>
    <a href="#top" rel="relativeanchor">Go Back to Top</a>
  </body>
</body>
</html>
```